# Getting link to video that iPhone uses for YouTube videos in Perl

Tags: iphone, perl, youtube

I want to download a video from Youtube in Perl. Specifically, I want to download the same version of the video that the iPhone Youtube application would download. I am testing getting YouTube videos on iPhone, so I would like to simulate this as closely as possible on a desktop, using Perl. What library can I use, and what URL should I access?

Answer (score 3):

Mobile devices use the [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) links provided in the [YouTube GData feeds](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html).  Specifically, you want to look for a [`format` of 1 or 6, which are the RTSP formats](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#formatsp).

If you want to get the information for a specific video, the link to get the feed for that video (from which you would get the RTSP link from) is:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<videoId>?v=2
```

Where `<videoId>` is replaced with the id of the video.